# cx_Oracle.STRING to Python string conversion

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

I am calling pl/sql procedure from python using cx_Oracle, procedure is executed successfully and am able to print the output message. I need to convert it to python string so that I can do equals check or iterate over it.

```
proc output variable: x_status

print(x_status) -> <cx_Oracle.STRING with value 'S'>
```

I had gone through cx_Oracle docs but not able to find how to convert it.
Any suggestions/help? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I tried str(x_status) it worked.. is this the right way ? or is there any better way to convert cx_Oracle objects to equivalent python objects.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a cx_Oracle variable object which is documented [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/variable.html). Specifically, you can use the [getvalue()](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/variable.html#Variable.getvalue) method to acquire the value.